# Thunderbird 'get mail' shortcut disallowed

Tags: 18.04, thunderbird, shortcuts

Running Thunderbird v60.9 on Bionic, the menu and documentation say F5 will 'Get new messages for current account.' But I get the 'no go' sign flashing up. I've got no immediate help from Mozilla forum. Anyone else seen this?

[image]

Comment: F5 is the refresh shortcut. It works in TB for me with 6..9 and 18.04. What does it do in your browser?

Comment: Thank you, Graham. I hadn't noticed that, but I get the same 'no go' in Firefox. Is 'refresh', then, the same as 'get new messages on current account?' That's not obvious.

Comment: Have you checked in Settings>Devices>Keyboard Shortcuts to see how F5 is configured?

Comment: Yes, I did that when I read your previous post. Nothing there.

Comment: I have just discovered that 'F5' in LibreOffice basic, which should mean 'run macro' produces the same 'no' symbol. Is this perhaps a hardware problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, my bad. It seems that by default on Dell laptops when you hit an F (F1-F12) key it generates Fn-F, and if you type Fn-F it generates the 'normal' F thing. Seems crazy, and it can be inverted in Bios or by typing Fn+Esc.